# How is the Stack Exchange CAPTCHA system implemented?

Tags: discussion, support, stack-exchange, captcha, implementation

**How does the CAPTCHA system in the Stack Exchange platform work behind-the-scenes?**

Specifically, after the system decides to display a challenge to the user, how is the result URL stored? Furthermore, in instances when a CAPTCHA is displayed during a form submission: how and where is the form data stored?

**Edit:** We already know that it uses ReCAPTCHA (based on many architecture blogposts/answers) - my question is about how the platform is structured around ReCAPTCHA; e.g. where the form data is stored.

Comment: Good try, Robot

Comment: @Pekka: lol :D full disclosure: I'm making an ASP.NET MVC website where I'm trying to implement a similar system.

Answer (score 4):

It uses [reCAPTCHA](http://recaptcha.net/).

As for the form data, I assume it is stored in `<input type="hidden">` fields.

Answer (score 2):

[ReCaptcha](http://www.google.com/recaptcha) provides the actual captcha services. There is a [Codeplex project for MVC ReCaptcha in C#](http://mvcrecaptcha.codeplex.com/). I haven't personally used it, but it looks to have good documentation and has good reviews. It might be a bit outdated though.